# Kubernetes Istio sidecars namespaces

Tags: cluster, kubernetes

I am currently evaluating the istio mesh within a bare metal kubernetes deployment. Everything just fine so far, I use the sidecar auto injection with the namespace labels.

Now to my question:

**Should the namespaces kube-system and istio-system be labeled for sidecar injection as well?** Or is this not advisable?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Should the namespaces kube-system and istio-system be labeled for sidecar injection as well?**

No, it should not.

It's against security rules.

> - sidecars cannot be injected in the  `kube-system`  or  `kube-public`  namespaces
> - sidecars cannot be injected into pods that use the host network

Please read this [Sidecar Injection Webhook](https://istio.io/docs/ops/setup/injection/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, does this apply to istio-system as well?

Comment: If you read the docs you will see they enabled only `default` for injection and `disabled` istio-system, kube-public and kube-system.

Comment: In the default deployment there is no disabled label for those namespaces. The example you linked even shows: 

kubectl label namespace istio-system istio-injection=disabled --overwrite 

Which shouldn't be allowed for the istio-system namespace, correct?

Comment: Yes, `default` is the only one enabled. Others are `disabled`.